# C++ in Xcode: Use of undeclared identifier from macro generated enum

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-c++, macros, enums

I am given this set of code that have a macro generate an enumeration during compile time.

```
MakeEnum4(EnumName, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4);
```

MakeEnum4 is the alias for another macro function with the following definition:

```
/// Here _Indexed() is an empty macro
#define MakeEnum4(name,v1,v2,v3,v4) _Expand4(name, _Indexed(), v1, v2, v3, v4)
```

_Expand4 is defined as follows:

```
#define _Expand4(name, mode, value1, value2, value3, value4)                    \
  namespace name                                                                \
  {                                                                             \
     typedef uint Type;                                                         \
     // cstr is typedef as const char*                                          \
     static const cstr EnumName = #name;                                        \
     enum Enum { value1 = mode 0, value2 = mode 1, value3 = mode 2,             \
                 value4 = mode 3 };                                             \
     enum { Size = 4 };                                                         \ 
     static const cstr Names[] = { #value1, #value2, #value3, #value4, NULL };  \
  }                                                                             \
```

So here's the issue:

In some header file an enum was generated, let's call it Declaration.h:

```
//in Declaration.h

MakeEnum4(SomeEnum, TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD);
```

Then in another file call FooHeader.h, a template function is calling this generated enumeration SomeEnum:

```
//in FooHeader.h

template < typename type >
SomePtr* Foo(cstr name, SomeType*& someType, /*unrelated function pointer*/)
{
  someType = new SomeType(name, sizeof(type), CompileTimeId<type>(), SomeEnum::TypeA);
  //...
}
```

Here SomeEnum is flagged by the C++ compiler that Xcode uses as "Use of undeclared identifier 'SomeEnum'". The same set of code compile fine on Visual Studio 2010. And this project is a cross-platform project for a same set of C++ libraries to be ported over to Apple's platform.

I am thinking that it might be due to the enumeration not being generated in time for FooHeader.h's translation unit but I have no idea how to get around it. Any insight on this is appreciated.

Sorry if the code I provided are cryptic, that's because the content is under some very strict NDA on my end.

Comment: Look at preprocessor-generated file to see what happens.

Comment: might you ask a question?

Comment: The only way this could happen (unless you haved any earlier errors that you're not mentioning) is if "Declaration.h" isn't included in, or before, "FooHeader.h". Are you using precompiled headers or have platform-dependent includes?

Comment: `1.` You're using reserved names (`_Expand4`, `_Indexed`) - anything starting with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter is reserved for the compiler & standard library. `2.` I'm afraid there's not enough info the question. What's `_Indexed()`? Does `FooHeader.h` include `Declaration.h`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I have tried including Declaration.h but that does not resolve this issue. The code is written in pure C++ and no platform dependency. In fact, I was given this project entirely in the window compilable state and is tasked to create the environment in Xcode. All I did so far, was to setup the Xcode project for these static libraries related files as it is in MSVC.

Comment: @Angew _Indexed() is an empty macro. It's definition is just 

    `#define _Indexed()`

Also as stated in my reply to molbdnilo I have tried including Declaration.h in FooHeader.h but the same error is still generated.

Comment: @AlexFarber yeah I have looked at all the related files. But I still cannot figure out what's wrong. I have filter the issue down to these 2 files.

Comment: @XavierRXTan Please try to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - something we could copy & paste verbatim to e.g. [ideone](http://ideone.com/) and see the error ourselves. Then we'll be much more able to help. And `Declaration.h` **must** be included wherever you want to use `SomeEnum`. This isn't something you should just "try;" you *must* be doing this.

Comment: You should really look at the output from the preprocessor, with clang/gcc you do that by passing `-E` to the command line. Then just look at the code that the compiler sees and figure out the problem.

Comment: I have looked at the preprocessor-generated output. The generated SomeEnum indeed came after the definition of Foo function residing in FooHeader.h